# My C# program gives an error "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"

Tags: c#, console

I am getting an error trying to write a program that displays the first 5 lines of a large file.

```
C:\blah\aeea2>for /L %f in (1,1,500) do @echo zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz >>testfile
```

That above generates my file.  It's 500 lines with those z characters on each line.

```
C:\blah\aeea2>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\blah\aeea2

16/10/2016  05:48 AM    <DIR>          .
16/10/2016  05:48 AM    <DIR>          ..
16/10/2016  05:42 AM               388 prog.csc
16/10/2016  05:42 AM             4,096 prog.exe
16/10/2016  05:48 AM            19,500 testfile
               3 File(s)         23,984 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,879,127,552 bytes free
```

You see my program here

```
C:\blah\aeea2>type prog.csc
class a{
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
       string line;
       System.Collections.Generic.List<string> lststr = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
       int i=0;
       while( (line=System.Console.In.ReadLine())!=null ) {i++;  lststr.Add(line);  if(i==5) break;}
       for(i=0; i<lststr.Count; i++) System.Console.WriteLine(lststr[i]);
   }
}
```

And here is the bug

```
C:\blah\aeea2>type testfile| prog.exe
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

C:\blah\aeea2>
```

But it works for a very small file

```
C:\blah\aeea2>type smallfile.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
C:\blah\aeea2>type smallfile.txt| prog.exe
a
b
c
d
e

C:\blah\aeea2>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `System.Console.In.ReadLine()` and not `System.Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain because in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066405/c-sharp-how-can-i-read-data-piped-to-my-program-without-prompting-when-nothing   a commenter said I should read form the stream itself and I said I need to read each line and he said ok read one line at a time. I didn't know what he meant but so I changed it from System.Console.ReadLine() to that with In.  I can change it back.. But I get the same error either way.

Comment: Marc,  when I said my program gives an error, I meant running my program gives an error.. i.e. that it's not necessarily inherent to my program, whereas the way you worded the title it sounds like it's inherent.. granted my program can prevent that error from appearing, but it's not like it's my program that is "throwing" it also c# has exceptions that are thrown so I wouldn't use the word 'throw' here for an error that doesn't originate from my program(though is influenced by it) and is not an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not your program, it's actually the `type` command.

`type` will try writing the full file content to the pipe and send it to your program. But your program consumes only first 5 lines and exits. Therefore `type` complains about no longer existing consumer (pipe).

In order to make it working without warnings/errors, it may be better to consume full input instead of breaking after `i == 5` and just throw it out. However, it'll waste CPU and IO by reading something which is not needed.

The reason why it works for smaller files is that the remaining bytes fit into pipe buffer (usually 4kB, 8kB, not 100% sure on all Windows systems).

**added by barlop**

Some interesting findings involving the above, and the commands,  gnuwin32 cat, cygwin cat, and the environments cmd, and cygwin, I found the following.

They all work (/ don't run into error), with zbynek's adjustment(making my program read the lot).

But without zbynek's adjustment -

The gnuwin32 cat command does not work from cmd, it behaves similarly to type and after outputting the lines, it says "write error: Invalid argument"

The cygwin cat command if done from cmd, does not work, it says "write error: No space left on device"

The windows 'more' command works from cmd(or unsurprisingly, from cygwin). So that can be used instead of 'type'.

And from cygwin, cat - either the gnuwin32 cat or the cygwin cat, work.

I would've tested 'type' from cygwin but I tried and I don't think cygwin can run type, it's built into the cmd.exe shell and doesn't have its own executable and I don't think cygwin can see it.

Comment: Thanks that works.. I will consider adding an option to the program to set it to read all input, and the user can choose to use that switch when using type (or some other command that is broken in the way type is), to send input in.

Comment: I suppose one could write a program `type thatfile | intermediateprogram | prog`

Comment: Any idea why replacing type with 'less' and it doesn't throw an error?  less still seems to send all the characters to stdout. `less testfile | wc -l` is 500 as type does.. But for some reason  `less  testfile | head -n 1`,  doesn't give the error whereas type does.

Comment: W10 PowerShell type probably send file line by line to pipe.